# Android Object Animation xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation, objectanimator

I am trying to create translate a image (ball) using the xml objectAnimator. When I try to reference my objectAnimator xml file, it says getApplicationContext() might return null. When I flash it to my phone, it crashed immediately. When I take out that line and the setAnimationListener line, it works. However, if there is just one of those lines, it does not work.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
Animation.AnimationListener{

ImageView ball;
Button moveb1;

Animation move;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);
    moveb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.move1);

    move = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.animator.move);

    move.setAnimationListener(this);
}
}
```

move.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="together">
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:duration="500"
    android:valueTo="400"
    android:valueType="intType"/>
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:duration="500"
    android:valueTo="300"
    android:valueType="intType"/>
</set>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post logcat output of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AnimationUtils:createAnimationFromXml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.java#AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml%28android.content.Context,org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,android.view.animation.AnimationSet,android.util.AttributeSet%29)

line 112 - 125
android have not support "objectAnimator"

maybe you need is AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator